# NSJSONSerialization get error "index 1 beyond bounds for empty array"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

sometimes I get error "index 1 beyond bounds for empty array" at this line

```
NSData *aData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

This is my full code

```
+ (NSDictionary *)getJson: (NSString *)strURL parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters{
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:nil];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:15.0];

    NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"application/json",
                               @"cache-control": @"no-cache",
                               @"postman-token": @"374a4b6f-b660-78f2-78bf-e22cf0156d8d"};

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    NSData *aData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];*

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:aData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    return json;
}
```

Sometimes I get error, Sometimes not. I don't understands ? please help me, thanks everyone.

Comment: put breakpoint and find exactly where it's crashing , post the stacktrace here. it'll be helpfull to solve the issue

Comment: Issue doesn't seem to be on the line you mentioned...

Comment: [link]http://prntscr.com/bbeoaz
[link]http://prntscr.com/bbeoms
this is my error.

Comment: are you using some array to store values ?

Comment: no, i'm using nsdictionary to store request parameters and nsdata to store response data

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get an error like the above, try the following:

```
NSData *aData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:aData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

if (error)
{
    //1. See what the error says
    NSLog(error.localizedDescription);

    //2. Convert the original data into a string
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:aData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //Now take this string and validate it as a JSON at a place like http://jsonlint.com/
}
```

Comment: I put your code in my project, but it's still crash at sendSynchronousRequest line, I can't see what error says

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url
                                                                cachePolicy: defaultCachePolicy
                                                            timeoutInterval: defaultTimeoutInSeconds];
```

plz change your cachePolicy with defaultCachePolicy and try :)

Comment: i don't see defalultCachePolicy in list of cachePolicy [link]http://prntscr.com/bbq1jd ???